# Reject tx on component re-render

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I am making a webapp using react and ethers.js that works with metamask. If I call MyContract.MyFunc(xyz, function(error, result){ }); user will see a metamask popup. My code will get a response only if user presses SUBMIT or REJECT. But if the user refreshes the page without pressing either SUBMIT or REJECT, my code will never know the status of this transaction although the user is still able to submit this transaction.

The first part of my code sends a transaction and the second part posts info to my api. My issue is that the transaction part of the code produces a metamask popup for the user to confirm and sign the transaction. If the user continues with the transaction as expected my code work without problems. However, if the user refreshes the page or otherwise resets the state of my component after the metamask popup is produced and before they confirm it and then confirm it after the page reload, then I'm unable to post the data to my api and my app breaks. What can I do to stop this? Is there a way to reject transactions on page reloads or check if there unsigned transactions on metamask?

```
    try {
      const price = await connectedContract.getMintPrice();
      const transaction = await connectedContract.primeMint({
        value: price,
      });
      const receipt = await transaction.wait();
      blockNumber = receipt.blockNumber;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      setState({ ...state, button: false });
    }
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/api/mints", {
        _id: _address,
        blockNumber: blockNumber,
      })
      .then(() => {
        setState({
          status: "Loading",
          blockNumber: blockNumber,
          button: false,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        setState({ ...state, button: false });
      });
```

Comment: Try put the related code in your back-end of the site instead of front-end and make a listener in back-end and filter it!